# how to model Marriage entity with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Let's say that you have an Person entity as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "person_id")
  private long id;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255)")
  private String name;

  ...       
}
```

Now say that you want to define a Marriage entity, holding two Person, with a start date, an end date (end date might be null if still married), and nrOfChildren.

How would you approach this?

One way could be to add the following to the Person entity:

```
 @JoinTable(name = "Person_Marriage",
      joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "marriage_id")})
private Set<Marriage> marriages;
```

And have a Marriage entity as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Marriage {
    ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "marriages")
    private Set<Person> couple;  //always composed by two elements

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date married_from;
    ... 
}
```

Of course, the `couple` set above, would always only contain 2 elements, a constrain that I would enforce by code.

I guess something like this could work, but it seems rather sloppy, as I would also need to ensure by code that Marriage(A,B)=Marriage(B,A), if you get my point..

Do you have a better idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go maybe with making the 2 persons for the `Marriage` explicit with a composite key:

```java
@Entity @IdClass(MarriageId.class)
public class Marriage {
   @Id Person person1;
   @Id Person person2;
}
```

I'm unsure about the exact syntax for JPA, but you get the point. :)

Comment: Humm, and what is this MarriageId.class?

Comment: You need that to make a composite key in JPA, AFAIK.